# does jquery have an equivalent of dojo.connect()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dojo

Forgive my ignorance as I am not as familiar with jquery. Is there an equivalent to dojo.connect() ?

I found this solution : http://think-robot.com/2009/06/hitch-object-oriented-event-handlers-with-jquery/

But there isn't disconnect feature !

Do you know other solution in jquery ? There are jquery.connect but this plugin not work in my tests.

Thanks for your help,
Stephane

Comment: Note that dojo.connect is being replaced by the dojo/on function: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/on.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by an equivalent to dojo.connect() ?

If you are willing to create your own custom event handlers, look at *bind()*, *trigger()* and *proxy()* in the [Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

The *proxy()* function will alow your to redefine what *this* points to in your callback function.

Comment: > The proxy() function will alow your to redefine what this  points to in your callback function.


Great !

Comment: In dojotoolkit, I can do :

dojo.connect(obj, "on_custom_event", obj2, obj2.action);

obj can been DOM node or simple javascript object.

In jQuery, bind work only on DOM node element.

Answer (score 3):

The closest equivalent jQuery has is [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), for example:

```
$("#element").bind('eventName', function(e) {
 //stuff
});
```

And [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove the handler, like this:

```
$("#element").unbind('eventName');
```

[There are also shortcuts for `.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/), so for example `click` can be done 2 ways:

```
$("#element").bind('click', function() { alert('clicked!'); });
//or...
$("#element").click(function() { alert('clicked!'); });
```

There is also [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) ([`.die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/) to unbind) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) ([`.undelegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) to unbind) for event handlers based on bubbling rather than being directly attached, e.g. for dynamically created elements.

The examples above were anonymous functions, but you can provide a function directly just like dojo (or any javascript really), like this:

```
$("#element").click(myNamedFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't as such but you can acheive the same thing as follows:

```
$('#someid').click(function() { SomeFunc($(this)) });
```

That will wire somefunc, to the click event of control with id "someid". When the control is clicked the function will be called and the parameter will be a jquery object that refers to control that was clicked.

**Update** I have just done a bit more research and i think [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [connect](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqConnect) is equivalent to dojo.connect.